# Static IP for google cloud functions (ingress)

Tags: function, google-cloud-platform, ip, cloud, serverless

I have two different projects. The first one have a API Gateway instance (KONG), which i want to connect with the 2nd one, which have a cloud function with an api (serverless). According the infrastructure team, I need to have a IP and port in my function to do that.

It was made a peering between both and now I want to set a static ip to my function. That is because the infrastructure guy has said me that it is necessary.

The questions are:

1. Is it necessary? Do I configure a static IP for my function?
2. How can I set a static IP to my function (ingress)?

Comment: 1. It depends on the requirements of your team. 2. Cloud Functions are serverless services, then natively it's not possible to assign a static IP. The approach for this is using a LB (Serverless NEG) https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/https/setting-up-https-serverless

Comment: Requiring an IP/PORT to perform a forward in an API Gateway in 2022 is weird. Domain name should be enough (and safer/easier to maintain). Any, the only solution is to use a HTTPS Load Balancer, as @Ferregina said.

Comment: I agree with @Ferregina. The only way to put a static ip address is by using LB (Serverless NEG) during configuration of LB there is a option to create a static ip or you can [create a static IP address](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/ip-addresses/reserve-static-external-ip-address#reserve_new_static) and assigned it to LB.

Can you share with us your teams plan why they are required to have a static ip and what are they next move once follow to have LB for static ip address.